# Group listed objects based on name and source as a key in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to group the list elements based on the combination of list items. I have read the test data from the csv and stored it in i list.

```
String file = test.csv;
List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<String[]>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
  String line = "";
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    content.add(line.split(","));
  }
```

Now the list contain the data, how to group the items based on the name and source and stored in the list.

Here is my sample csv file
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by grouping the items? Could you provide an example of what end result you expect?

Comment: What is the desired output type (sorted list, map with composite key, multiple lists, ...)?

Comment: This is what i am expecting the out put
{[John Lennon, wikipedia.com]=[name=john Lenon, birthDate=09-10-1940, birthPlace.address.street=Liverpool, birthPlace.address.city=Lancashire, birthPlace.address.country=England, spouse.first_name=Cynthia, spouse.last_name=Powell], [Paul Allen, twitter.com]=[name=Paul Allen, birthDate=, birthPlace.address.street=1800 pembrook drive, birthPlace.address.city=florida, birthPlace.address.country=United States], [person name, source]=[field name]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use new IO classes `Path` and `Files` to read the input file as a stream of strings and then use Stream API with `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping` to get a map like `Map<List<String>, List<String>>`:

```java
Map<List<String>, List<String>> map = Files.lines(Path.of(csvFileName))        // get stream of lines from the input CSV file
        .map(s -> s.split(","))  // split a line into columns
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            // a key is a list of `name` and `source` columns
            arr -> Arrays.asList(arr[0], arr[2]),
            // a value is a list of field names in column #1
            Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())
        ));
System.out.println(map);
```

Example output:

```
{[John Lennon, wiki]=[name, birthDate], [Paul McCartney, wiki]=[name, birthDate, birthPlace]}
```

Comment: How can i store the expected value the last column based on the key